# Grouped operation in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Good afternoon,

Let look at the following simple example :

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1L)
dt1 <- data.table(
  v1=rep(c("foo", "bar"), 2L),
  v2=runif(4L)
)
dt1[]

##      v1        v2
##  1: foo 0.2655087
##  2: bar 0.3721239
##  3: foo 0.5728534
##  4: bar 0.9082078
```

I'd like to know how to calculate and assign by reference a column `v3` which is the division of the `bar` elements by the `foo` elements, giving the following

```
##      v1        v2       v3
##  1: foo 0.2655087 1.401551
##  2: bar 0.3721239 1.401551
##  3: foo 0.5728534 1.585411
##  4: bar 0.9082078 1.585411
```

I'm almost sure there is an easy way of doing so, but I can't find how.

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: see `?rowid`, if I understood your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has requested to divide each `bar` element by its immediately preceeding `foo` element and to assign the quotient to both rows.

#### Group by using `cumsum()`

This can be implemented as an `update by group` using `cumsum(v1 == "foo")` to create unique group ids:

```
dt1[, v3 := last(v2)/first(v2), by = cumsum(v1 == "foo")][]
```

> ```
>     v1        v2       v3
> 1: foo 0.2655087 1.401551
> 2: bar 0.3721239 1.401551
> 3: foo 0.5728534 1.585411
> 4: bar 0.9082078 1.585411
> ```

Instead of `last()` and `first()` we can also write:

```
dt1[, v3 := v2[.N]/v2[1], by = cumsum(v1 == "foo")][]
```

#### Group by using `rowid()`

Instead of `cumsum(v1 == "foo")`, `rowid(v1)` can be used as well:

```
dt1[, v3 := v2[.N]/v2[1], by = rowid(v1)][]
```

> ```
>     v1        v2       v3
> 1: foo 0.2655087 1.401551
> 2: bar 0.3721239 1.401551
> 3: foo 0.5728534 1.585411
> 4: bar 0.9082078 1.585411
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Uwe, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Following @MichaelChirico's suggestion of using `rowid`, we can do the division by subsetting the values, then assign the new column.

```
dt1[, v3 := (dt1[v1 == "bar", v2] / dt1[v1 == "foo", v2])[rowid(v1)]]
dt1
#     v1        v2       v3
# 1: foo 0.2655087 1.401551
# 2: bar 0.3721239 1.401551
# 3: foo 0.5728534 1.585411
# 4: bar 0.9082078 1.585411
```

Comment: Another way to use rowid: `dcast(dt1, rowid(v1) ~ v1, value.var="v2")[, rat := bar/foo][]`